# Wrap each line text to an element using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this

```
<div class="mad-select">
<ul class="madSelect">
Hours
Days
Weeks
Months
</ul></div>
```

Then i want to make it like this by using JQuery

```
<div class="mad-select">
<ul class="madSelect">
    <li>Hours</li>
    <li>Days</li>
    <li>Weeks</li>
    <li>Months</li>
</ul></div>
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first access the text inside `<ul>` then split them. After that just clear anything in `<ul>` then add the `<li>`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

var arr = $('.madSelect').html().split('\n');
$('.madSelect').empty();

$.each(arr, function( index, value ) {
  if ( index > 0 && index < arr.length - 1) 
    $('.madSelect').append("<li>"+arr[index]+"</li>");
});



});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mad-select">
<ul class="madSelect">
Hours
Days
Weeks
Months
</ul></div>
```

EDIT:

I changed from  `.text()` to `.html()`, because `.html()` is ~2x faster than `.text()`if you have **only a text**.